# I am getting this error from the following code,what might be the reason and how do I solve it?

Tags: javascript

Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

```
 var Attraction_sitesLayer= L.geoJson(Attraction_sites,{    
onEachFeature: function(feature,featureLayer) {     featureLayer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Tourist attraction Sites);    
}
 }).addTo(newMap);
```

Comment: Please add the language tag

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the indexing syntax, i.e. brackets, when accessing an attribute of an object that is not a valid identifier.

```
var Attraction_sitesLayer = L.geoJson(Attraction_sites, {
  onEachFeature: function(feature, featureLayer) {
    featureLayer.bindPopup(feature.properties["Tourist attraction Sites"]);
  }
}).addTo(newMap);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @AKX it worked